# Are angularjs has any ways to update the ng-model and the input text value separately?

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive to get the lat log form google map api 
and autocomplete the address

```
 .directive('googleplace', function() {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, model) {
                var options = {
                    types: [],
                    componentRestrictions: {}
                };
                scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], options);
                google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {
                    var geoComponents = scope.gPlace.getPlace();
                    var latitude = geoComponents.geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = geoComponents.geometry.location.lng();

                    var location = {
                        address : element.val(),
                        latitude : latitude,
                        longitude : longitude
                    };

                    attrs.$set('data-lat', location.latitude);
                    attrs.$set('data-lon', location.longitude);

                    //if ng-model=locations 
                    //input text will become [Object][Object]
                    //model.$setViewValue(location);

                    model.$setViewValue(location.address);
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

and the html code:

```
  <input type='text' ng-model="locations[$index].address" googleplace ng-repeat="location in locations"/>
```

model - `locations` is an object array like this:

```
[{
  address : 'xxxxxxx',
  latitude : 22.3432,
  longitude : 144.34234
},{
  address : 'aaaaa',
  latitude : 22.3233,
  longitude : 145.3432
} ...]
```

I change the text in input, the address is updated  , that's ok.
but How can i get update the latitude and longitude in `locations`

if the ng-model is `locations` instead of `locations.address`, the input text become `[Object] [Object]`

I try to use attribute `data-lat` and `data-lon`, but there is no easy way to get the attribute value on change, since `ng-change` cannot pass the target DOM to controller function.

Are there are a way to update the model and the input text value separately??
Or a way to get the attribute value on change??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recomment to use ui-Bootstraps typeahead for this, which brings a lot of options to make the auto-complete behave in your way.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#typeahead

You there could put the location as ng-model and use the typeahead attribute

```
ng-model="locations[$index]"
typeahead="location as location.address for location in getLocations($viewValue)"
```

The getLocations has to be implemented in your controller and $viewValue references to the input-field text

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It works but have a problem work with ng-repeat .I guess it is because the scope is keep changing, and the ng-repeat keep update, cannot stable to make autocomplete. I use another $scope variable - tmplocations for the ng-repeat, and use locations[$index] for ng-model. I update your answer with my final code.